# Centering divs after utilizing floats

Tags: html, css

I have this currently:

[image]

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

Basically centering the content vertically. I've tried with:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Just doesn't seem to get there.

https://jsfiddle.net/pjvxh34h/

How it looks in fiddle for me:

[image]

css:

```
div.avatar-name-signout-container {
  background:lightblue;
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
}

div.avatar-name {
  float: right;
  background: lime;  
}

div.avatar {
    display:inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url('http://diondifc.com/img/team_pic1.jpg');
}

div.name {
  float:right;
}

div.signout {
  float:right;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="avatar-name-signout-container">
    <div class="signout">
      sign out
    </div>
    <div class="avatar-name">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="name">Karl</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @RonenCypis Doooone :)

Comment: The content in that fiddle looks centered vertically to me?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode Added image displaying how it looks for me!

Comment: Check my answer... looks like you wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you change most of your divs to be spans, it's easier to control them using the `line-height` property, and vertically align them. check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/9hrsuj27/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="avatar-name-signout-container">
    <span class="signout">
      sign out
    </span>
    <span class="avatar-name">
      <span class="avatar"></span>
      <span class="name">Karl</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.avatar-name-signout-container {
  background:lightblue;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  width:300px;
}


.avatar-name {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background: lime;  
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.avatar {
    display:inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url('http://diondifc.com/img/team_pic1.jpg');
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.name {
  float:right;
}

.signout {
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest methid is not to use floats at all.

If you amend the HTML and set everything to `display:inline-block` you can mage the rest with `text-align` and `vertical-align`.

```css
div.avatar-name-signout-container {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
}
div.avatar-name {
  background: lime;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://diondifc.com/img/team_pic1.jpg');
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.signout {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-name-signout-container">

  <div class="avatar-name">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name">Karl</div>
  </div>
  <div class="signout">
    sign out
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can perhaps use `margin-top:50px;` to fix this up.

Please mark as answer if that helped.